# How to extract name/value pairs with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have data of the type

```
<preference>
  <name>throttle_scan</name>
  <value>yes</value>
</preference>
  <preference><name>listen_address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</preference>
```

These are essentially name/value pairs I would like to extract with BeautifulSoup.

I managed to extract a list of `preference`

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(string_with_xml, 'html.parser')
for p in soup.find_all('preference'):
    c = p.contents
    print(c)
```

gives a list per `preference`:

```
[<name>throttle_scan</name>, '\n', <value>yes</value>, '\n']
[<name>listen_address</name>, '\n', <value>0.0.0.0</value>, '\n']
```

**How can I further drill down this list?** Should I go though a new

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(''.join(c), 'html.parser')
```

and search `name` and `value`?

Comment: Why not use lxml instead of 'html.parser' so you can actually leverage that functionality to access the child nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do like this,

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''<preference>
  <name>throttle_scan</name>
  <value>yes</value>
</preference>
  <preference><name>listen_address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</preference>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> for i in soup.select('preference'):
    print i.find('name').text
    print i.find('value').text
    print '-----------'


throttle_scan
yes
-----------
listen_address
0.0.0.0
-----------
>>>
```

`soup.select` works same as `soup.find_all` but here we may pass `css` selectors which would make your life easier. For ex, to select all the tags having the class `foo`, you could use,

```
soup.select('.foo')
```

`.` represents `class` and `#` represents `id` of a tag.

Comment: Thank you. While I see that `.select()` is indeed documented, I found it under CSS parsing, which may not be obvious for someone starting with th module. (waiting the cooldown time to accept)

Comment: @Woj I love `select` than `find_all` :-)